# How to use ReQL filter and match command on arrays

Tags: rethinkdb, reql

I have a table in rethinkdb where each row has following structure -

```
{
  'name':'clustername',
  'services':[
     {
        'name':'service1'
     },
     {
        'name':'service2'
     }
  ]
}
```

I am running a query to filter service2 object like this

```
r.table('clusters').filter({"name":  "clustername"})
  .pluck('services').filter((service) => { 
     return service("name").match('service2')
  })
```

But this is not returning anything: `No results were returned for this query`

Can anyone tell why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pluck` returns sequence, so this query:

```
r.table('clusters').filter({"name":  "clustername"}).pluck('services')
```

will return:

```
{

    "services": [
        {
            "name": "service1"
        } ,
        {
            "name": "service2"
        }
    ]

}
```

You need get `services` field from it, it will return array with `services` field of items found by `filter`.

And after that you need to use your second filter on each item by using `map`.

So, correct query:

```
r.table('clusters').filter({"name": "clustername"}).pluck('services')("services").map(item => {
    return item.filter(service => { 
      return service("name").match("service2");
    });

})
```